Storing AWA Secrets from SecretManager to Repository
Would like to understand does anyone commits the AWS Secret Manager CloudFormation file to private repository ?
If not how should the team manage the changes and version control the configuration ?

Are you referring to secrets values? Or Cloudformation template?

hi @Dev4ever, i am referring to the CF template. It has the secrets stored within the CF yaml file. Thanks !

It's not a good practice to store secrets in a CloudFormation template. You should always keep your configuration separated from your code.
You can use:

Parameter store for general configuration (URLs / resources names / ...)
Parameter store with Secure String type
Secrets manager
AWS AppConfig for feature flags type of configuration

Best approach would be to put most of your configuration in Parameter store, and use Parameter store with Secure String type or Secrets manager only for sensible information.
For versioning, you can use Secrets manager versioning and save up to 100 versions per secret.

I think it's security risk to store secrets in CloudFormation templates, even in private repositories. You may store all secrets directly in AWS Secrets Manager and use secret references in your CloudFormation when needed. As for version control, there is AWS Secrets Manager's built-in configuration.
